# What is the best way to use openmp with multiple subroutines in Fortran

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a program written in Fortran and I have more than 100 subroutines. However, I have around 30 subroutines where there are open-mp codes present. I was wondering what is the best procedure to compile these subroutines. When I used the all the files to compile at once then I found that open mp compiled code runs even slower than the one without open-mp. Should I compile the subroutines with open-mp tags separately ? What is the best practice under these conditions ?

Thank you so much.

Best Regards, 
Jdbaba

Comment: The order of compiling your subroutines, as long as it is legal (e.g., modules may have to be compiled first), shouldn't effect the run time of your program.  If the OpenMP version is taking longer to run then the regular version, you probably have a design problem with how you made your program parallel.  You may have contention between threads for access to the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenMP-aware compilers look for the OpenMP pragma (the open signs after a comment symbol at the begin of the line). Therefore, sources without OpenMP code compiled with an OpenMP-aware compiler should result on the exact or very close object files (and executable).

Edit: One should note that as stated by Hristo Iliev below, enabling OpenMP could affect the serial code, for example by using OpenMP versions of libraries that may differ in algorithm (to be more effective in parallel) and optimizations.

Most likely, the problem here is more related to your code algorithms.
Or perhaps you did not compile with the same optimization flags when comparing OpenMP and non-OpenMP versions.

Comment: One should be careful when making general statements like the second one in the first paragraph. With most compilers, enabling OpenMP support usually affects the serial code by turning on or off specific (and sometimes obscure) optimisations. It could also result in different (e.g. reentrant or more OpenMP-friendly) versions of the standard library functions being used instead.

Comment: @HristoIliev I totally agree and modify my answer immediately. Thank you.

Comment: @ max and @ Hristo lliev, Thank you so much for your time and suggestions. Yes, I also thought the problem is related to my algorithms. I used the same optimization flag. The only flag I used is ifort *.for -c for case without openmp and ifort *.for -c -openmp for case with openmp. And after that i used ifort *.for -o programname for case without openmp and ifort *.for -o programname -openmp. In my program the number of threads is read as arguments. Would you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637538/is-this-the-proper-way-to-define-number-of-threads-in-an-fortran-program ?

Comment: Would you also suggest me some optimization flag that would speed up the program ?