# Is this the proper way to define number of threads in an fortran Program?

Tags: fortran, openmp

I have a FORTRAN program written for the parallel computing. The program takes the arguments and the number of threads can be defined as the argument. The sample code is as follows:

```
COUNT = NARGS()
      NTHREADS = 1

      ! *** GET THE COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS, IF ANY
      IF(COUNT.GT.1)THEN
        ! *** ARGUMENT 1
        CALL GETARG(1, BUFFER, iStatus)
        IF (Buffer(1:4).EQ.'-NOP'.OR.Buffer(1:4).EQ.'-nop') THEN
          PAUSEIT=.FALSE.
        ENDIF
        IF (Buffer(1:3).EQ.'-NT'.OR.Buffer(1:3).EQ.'-nt') THEN
          READ(Buffer(4:10),*) NTHREADS
        ENDIF
        IF(COUNT.GT.2)THEN
          ! *** ARGUMENT 2
          CALL GETARG(2, BUFFER, iStatus)
          IF (Buffer(1:4).EQ.'-NOP'.OR.Buffer(1:4).EQ.'-nop') THEN
            PAUSEIT=.FALSE.
          ENDIF
          IF (Buffer(1:3).EQ.'-NT'.OR.Buffer(1:3).EQ.'-nt') THEN
            READ(Buffer(4:10),*) NTHREADS
          ENDIF
         ENDIF
      ENDIF
```

Let's say my compiled file name is "hellofortran". I can define the number of threads as

```
./hellofortran -nt4
```

My program will read the program with 4 threads. The problem is that I can run with as many cores in any computer. Lets say I have dual core processor. I have only two cores but I can still run with 6-8 threads or any number. How can I properly define the number of threads in this particular instance ?

I hope I explained my problem. Looking forward to hearing soon on how can I improve my program. Thanks.

Jdbaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using OpenMP and just looking to set up how many threads to use, I would just specify the number of threads in the environment:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4
./hellofortran
```

and write your OpenMP code as you would normally.  There are programmatic ways of setting thread counts but this is likely more straightforward for you.

Comment: @ Tim, Thank you so much for your answer . Can I also use inside the program as OMP_NUM_THREADS=NTHREADS ?

Comment: You could use the OpenMP function `omp_set_num_threads` but that's typically used for the situation where you might want to have different thread counts for different loops within the same program.  If you want the same thread count throughout, you can just set it in the environment. See http://www.ncsu.edu/itd/hpc/Courses/8shared.html for an example.